# Concatenate a list with a list of lists

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I need to extend a list with a variable number of lists as in the following example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5]
c = [6, 7, 8, 9]
d = [b, c]
```

The command I'm looking for should operate on `a` and `d`, and should give the following output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

that is the same as the output of:

```
[a, b, c]
```

As a bonus, it would be good if the same command could operate with `d` defined as `(b, c)`.

Comment: You want to have the arrays rearranged so that `b` becomes `[4,5]`.  Correct?  Everyone thinks you made a typo, but maybe you want something complex

Comment: Sorry indeed I made a typo, now the original post is correct. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [6]: [a] + d
Out[6]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

To make it work when `d` is a tuple, change that to

```
[a] + list(d)
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question satisfying also the additional requirements.

Comment: Sorry to come back on this matter, this solution is perfectly ok for the example, but I found that it doesn't work for `[a] + b` or `[a] + list(b)`, where `[[1, 2, 3], 4, 5]` is produced.

Comment: @gaggio `[a]` is a 'list of lists', `b` isn't. You need `[a]+[b]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [20]: d.insert(0,a)

In [21]: d
Out[21]: [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `[a,b,c]` should be `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]` in your example. Is this what you want ?
If so, doing `e = [a,]+list(d)` should work.